# Visual Studio 2013 Professional, TypeScript 1rc, no Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, intellisense

I was using TypeScript 0.9.5 during a project, and then upgraded to rc1.

After I did this, although TypeScript is installed and my code works as expected, I have lost all formatting and intellisense.

I have uninstalled Visual Studio and done several reboots. However, I still come back to the same issue.

Has anyone experienced this and know a way to resolve it?

Further Findings:

It is impossibly slow to type source code. Often resulting in the blue warning "Formatting Task Took Longer than 2 seconds to complete. Please try again..."

Comment: What are the installed plugins besides ts. PS do you have other versions of visual studio installed as well?

Comment: Check your tsc-related plugins configuration.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. No plugins installed besides ts. Also, only one vs2013 installed.

Answer (score 0):

> 'It is impossibly slow to type source code. Often resulting in the blue warning "Formatting Task Took Longer than 2 seconds to complete. Please try again..."'

I had the same w/ clean install of VS2013 Express Web Update 2 RC and found [this old bug](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/779) which was fixed a year ago so it seems to be a regression. Here's the workaround from the post:

> This is caused by an infinite loop in the logic that detects the extent of the statement that needs formatting after semicolon...go to your Tools\Options dialog then to Text Editor\Typescript\Formatting and check off "Format completed statements on ;". this will disable formatting after semicolon obviously, but should make VS usable again; this should not affect other formatting trigger points like new line and closing parentheses.

Restart Visual Studio for the change to take effect.

FYI: I've submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/846869/typescript-formatting-task-took-more-than-2-second-s-to-complete-try-again-later-in-vs2013-express-web-update-2-rc) to Microsoft on this issue. Perhaps you could vote it up the bug ticket.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me => click on

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Text Editor
4. All Languages
5. Ensure "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" are checked (no blue box).   Note: this addresses Intellisense (not performance)